# Enabling cors filters in two servers

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I have two servers in the nodejs app. 
I am using two servers `http-server` for static html file (i.e. index.html) and `express` for node APIs. Now I am getting the CORS filter error. even if I have enabled the cors filter on both the servers.

I have tried these combinations.
1. Enabling it on Node server using middleware.
i.e following code.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
  next();
});
```

and on `http-server` using following command.

`http-server --cors`

I am still getting following error.

[image: Error]

I am guessing here that enabling on both server won't work as both resources will have different CORS values. But how can I solve it? Any help would be appreciated.

Looking at the networks tab in the developer tools I can see following for the API request.
[image: Response to API]

**Update-1 tried cors package**

I have tried following code samples with each time a server restart.

```
app.use(cors());
```

and this one too.

```
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
```

and this one with specific configuration.

```
app.use(cors());

var whitelist = ['http://localhost:8080']
var corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
    }
  }
}
app.options('*', cors(corsOptions));
```

Everytime I am getting the same response in output console.

These are the routes.

```
module.exports = function(app){

  app.get('/get_tuna/:id', function(req, res){
    tuna.get_tuna(req, res);
  });
  app.get('/add_tuna/:tuna', function(req, res){
    tuna.add_tuna(req, res);
  });
  app.get('/get_all_tuna', function(req, res){
    console.log('###### ++++++++++ 2 - This is called first');
    tuna.get_all_tuna(req, res);
  });
  app.get('/change_holder/:holder', function(req, res){
    tuna.change_holder(req, res);
  });
  app.get('/api/get_available_vault_balance/', function(req, res){
    /// --------- 3
    console.log('VAULT >> API is called >>> :) ');
    vaultbackendservice.get_available_vault_balance(req, res);
  });
}
```

Comment: First things first, make sure browser is making preflight OPTIONS request. Does this happen? Do your servers respond correctly?

Comment: Not sure on this but I am looking into it, I have to do google a bit as I don't know how to check this.

Comment: I am getting 200OK for the API that I am calling I am updating that in question.

Comment: No problem. Open your developers tools (ie Chrom Dev Tools), and any time you make an AJAX request, there should be two requests sent: first, the preflight OPTIONS, which your CORS in the servers should respond to. Second is the original request you were trying to send.

Comment: You may consider using [this library](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) for Node.js/Express CORS, however I strongly advise that you understand what CORS is and how it works before using a third party library. It is really quite simple, you just gotta get it to click in your head for the first time. If you want you can open a chat with me and I can explain how CORS works.

Comment: I am not seeing anything else except the actual api call in the developer tools, I think I need to enable that OPTIONS request from angular side or is it by default enabled ?

Comment: If you aren't seeing anything then that means your server is not handling preflight CORS requests properly, which is why you get the CORS error when you make the request.

Comment: How to solve this ?

Comment: Did you look at the package I linked above? Read the [source code](https://github.com/expressjs/cors/blob/master/lib/index.js) and see how they handle CORS for Node.js, and then look at [their usage](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#usage) for that source code. Try to solve this. Me (or anyone else) giving you the answer won't help you learn! Feel free to ask when you are stumped and define the problem you are having.

Comment: I did install the cors module which you have mentioned I did enable the preflight thing as per this link: https://github.com/expressjs/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight for all available api links in my app but still it is showing me the same thing. I am not sure what is wrong here.

Comment: Can you try to be explicit with your allow origin? Instead of asterix *, use http:// localhost:8080 or whatever you are working from. Also make sure you have restarted your server to reflect the changes you made with CORS code.

Comment: Please check edit in question. I have listed the code which I have tried so far.

Comment: Show all your routes (with the cors code as well) as they are in your code.

Comment: You mean to say I have to put all my routes in the whitelist [] array ?

Comment: No, show me them. Did you read the comment lol? I said show your routes, not add them to whitelist :P The library says you must define all CORS, etc before your routes, so show your routes so I can see if they are configured properly with CORS.